# No output in debug area

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

In the debug area:

```
(lldb) po myObjectName
(lldb)
```

LLDB is giving an empty response for all my po or print queries. It seems like LLDB debug is not working anymore or not printing the debug messages.

Answer (score 17):

That was a silly one.

Simply select **All output** in the debug area, instead of **Target output**.

Comment: Silly perhaps, but very helpful if you just stepped into the exact same pitfall :)

Comment: And don't forget to clean "Filter" field in debug area :)